# How to get configurable product price programmatically in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, price

I am using a code to get product price on product detail page by using id

```
 var rprice1 = parseFloat( $('#product-price-'+id1).attr('data-price-amount'));
```

But when i click on swatch it does not get the swatch product price because id remains same.
This is magento 2 price code.

```
<span id="product-price-1065" data-price-amount="276" data-price-type="finalPrice" class="price-wrapper "><span class="price">276,00&nbsp;kr</span></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/layout/catalog_product_view_type_configurable.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="product.info.price">
            <block class="Magento\ConfigurableProduct\Block\Product\View\Type\Configurable" name="wk.info.pricerange"  template="Webkul_PriceRange::product/price_range.phtml" />
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/Vendor/Module/view/base/templates/price_range.phtml

```
<?php
$currentProduct = $this->getProduct();
$regularPrice = $currentProduct->getPriceInfo()->getPrice('regular_price');
?>
<div class='price-box'>
    <span class="price">
        <?php
            echo $regularPrice->getMinRegularAmount().'-'.$regularPrice->getMaxRegularAmount();
        ?>
    </span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory; 

public function __construct(
    ....
    CollectionFactory $productCollectionFactory
    ....
) {
    $this->products = $productCollectionFactory;
}

public function getConfigurableProductPrice()
{
    $products = $this->products->create();
    foreach($products as $product) {
        if ($product->getTypeId() != 'simple') {
            $specialPrice = $product->getSpecialPrice();
            $finalPrice=$_product->getFinalPrice();
            $savePercent = 100 - round(($finalPrice / 
            $specialPrice)*100);
            echo $savePercent.'% Off';
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Configurable products don't have any regular price or special price in Magento. On front end the price of their child products is taken as their regular price.

Comment: Configurable price have different price regarding with size etc.